# Accordion - How to not have first item expanded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm working on a site with a Accordion "function" based on this: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible

My only problem is that the first Section is open by default and I want every Section to be closed until the visitor presses them.

Someone know how to solve this?

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
collapsible: true
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="accordion">
<h3>Section 1</h3>
<div>
<p><img src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/300"></p>
</div>
<h3>Section 2</h3>
<div>
<p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna. </p>
</div>
<h3>Section 3</h3>
<div>
<p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis. Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui. </p>
<ul>
<li>List item one</li>
<li>List item two</li>
<li>List item three</li>
</ul>
</div>
<h3>Section 4</h3>
<div>
<p>Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia mauris vel est. </p><p>Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set [`active`](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active) option to `false`:

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
  collapsible: true,
  active: false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you initialise the `accordion` set the `active` property to `false`. This closes all panels:

```
$('#accordion').accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#accordion").accordion({ 
         collapsible: true, 
         active: false 
});
```

`active:false` will make the accordion closed

Note for other readers: You need `"collapsible: true"` to make `"active: false"` work.

Answer (score 1):

maybe it would be helpful if you would have read [the api](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#options) before asking

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
});
```